# Adding rates that happen one after another

Tags: arithmetic, education, applications

Suppose I have two operations that happen consecutively (**not simultaneously**), where the first operation has a rate of 3 units/hour and the second operation has a rate of 4 units/hour. Is there a way that I can add the two rates together so I can have just on rate instead?

Comment: Look up harmonic mean.

Comment: It depends on whether each operation runs for the same amount of time or produces the same number of units or something else

Comment: I think you also need to know each leg of the trip took same amount of time for harmonic mean to be what you want.

Comment: You process seven units in two hours.